# How would one apply the concept of DRY for repetitive array mapping tasks?

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures, mapping, dry

Given following code ...

```
// last 7 days data from db ...

let last7Days =
  result.map((data) => data._id).slice(1).slice(-7);

let last7daysIncome =
  result.map((data) => data.totalIncomeAmount).slice(1).slice(-7);

let last7daysAvgIncome =
  result.map((data)=> data.avrageIncome).slice(1).slice(-7);

let last7daysPatientionsCount =
  result.map((data)=> data.PatientionsCount).slice(1).slice(-7);

let last7disease =
  result.map((data)=>data.diseaseArr).slice(1).slice(-7);
```

... how would one simplify this code with the **DRY Concept** (**D**on't **R**epeat **Y**ourself) in JavaScript?

Comment: Giving a proper answer would be easier with some sample input data, instead of having it reverse engineered from all the mapper functionality (though sill being left puzzled about all the slicing).

Comment: `.slice(1).slice(-7)` is of no real use. In case one always wants to access the last 7 entries `.slice(-7)` already is totally sufficient. Also, one would always slice the `result` array *before* the mapping task and not after ... `result.slice(-7).map( /* */ )` ... The latter maps 7 items maximum. The former always and unnecessarily maps the entire `result` array (think about a lot of entries).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the OP obviously maps 5 times an array of data items, each time collecting another specific property value of such an item, one could come up with an approach which solves merging and collecting item entries in a generic way (agnostic to the underlaying data structure).

Merging array items into an object of grouped arrays is a classic [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) task which, with the next provided solution (due to its generic implementation) is done twice.

The following implementation in addition uses [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) in order to access each entry's key-value pair directly. It also utilizes the [*Logical nullish assignment / `??=`*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment) operator in order to access or create/assign an array with one line of code.

```js
function mergeAndCollectItemEntries(result, item) {
  return Object
    .entries(item)
    .reduce((merger, [key, value]) => {

      (merger[key] ??= []).push(value);
      return merger;

    }, result);
}

const sampleData = [
  { _id: 'foo', totalIncomeAmount: 10_000, last7daysAvgIncome: 2_500, PatientionsCount: 123, diseaseArr: ['long', 'sick', 'leave'] },
  { _id: 'bar', totalIncomeAmount: 8_000, last7daysAvgIncome: 2_000, PatientionsCount: 99, diseaseArr: ['very', 'long', 'sick', 'leave'] },
  { _id: 'baz', totalIncomeAmount: 4_000, last7daysAvgIncome: 1_000, PatientionsCount: 50, diseaseArr: ['really', 'long', 'sick', 'leave'] },
];

const {

  _id: last7Days,
  totalIncomeAmount: last7daysIncome,
  last7daysAvgIncome: avrageIncome,
  PatientionsCount: last7daysPatientionsCount,
  diseaseArr: last7disease,

} = sampleData.slice(-7).reduce(mergeAndCollectItemEntries, {});

console.log({
  last7Days,
  last7daysIncome,
  avrageIncome,
  last7daysPatientionsCount,
  last7disease,
} );

// was before ...
//
// // last 7 days data from db...
// 
// let last7Days =
//   result.map((data)=>data._id).slice(1).slice(-7);
// 
// let last7daysIncome =
//   result.map((data) => data.totalIncomeAmount).slice(1).slice(-7);
// 
// let last7daysAvgIncome =
//   result.map((data)=> data.avrageIncome).slice(1).slice(-7);
// 
// let last7daysPatientionsCount =
//   result.map((data)=> data.PatientionsCount).slice(1).slice(-7);
// 
// let last7disease =
//   result.map((data)=>data.diseaseArr).slice(1).slice(-7);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: @JacksonKasi ... you are certainly welcome. But do you also understand the main difference in between *Mads Hansen's* and the above approach? Are there any questions left about tackling the problem not only DRY but with a single generic reducer function as well? (here it's not about performance but about schools of thinking)

Comment: sir I need help please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70688467/how-to-convert-object-data-to-array-in-javascript-but-object-look-like-a-array

Comment: @JacksonKasi ... it is not very well received at SO to directly bump into people like this and asking for help on another topic/question ... nevertheless ... [here are my two cent on what I think is a data validity problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70688467/how-to-convert-typeof-obj-to-arr-in-javascript#comment124968001_70688467)

Answer (score 5):

Create a function, send in the parameter for the field you want to extract, and even the number of days to look back:

```
function lastDays(result, field, days) {
  return result.slice(days).map((data)=>data[field]);  
}
function lastSevenDays(result, field) {
  return lastDays(result, field, -7);
}

let last7Days = lastSevenDays(result, "_id")
let last7daysIncome = lastSevenDays(result, "totalIncomeAmount")
let last7daysAvgIncome  =lastSevenDays(result, "avrageIncome")
let last7daysPatientionsCount  = lastSevenDays(result, "PatientionsCount")
let last7disease = lastSevenDays(result, "diseaseArr")
```

Comment: really thanks sir :)

Comment: Good answer for a problem that looks like a school assignment, though.